# Order of iNaturalist taxon levels

Tags: taxonomy

## Purpose

I want to take a collection of iNaturalist observations and build a tree diagram of the taxonomic levels that occur in that sample.

## Background

Most of us have seen diagrams like this

[image]

or like this

[image]

that illustrate some of the taxonomic ranks that biologists assign organisms into.

I am looking at the data export options for iNaturalist and I see that there are more possibilities than conveyed in these simple diagrams. I am also unfamiliar with precisely what these added levels are telling us. I could ignore these additional levels, but I would rather not if they are biologically meaningful. I have tabulated these export variable options in the order that I am guessing they belong in, alongside the similar names mentioned on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank#Ranks_in_botany).

| iNaturalist | Wikipedia |
| --- | --- |
| `taxon_kingdom_name` | Kingdom |
| `taxon_phylum_name` | Phylum |
| `taxon_subphylum_name` | Subphylum |
| `taxon_superclass_name` |  |
| `taxon_class_name` | Class |
| `taxon_subclass_name` | Subclass |
| `taxon_superorder_name` |  |
| `taxon_order_name` | Order |
| `taxon_suborder_name` | Suborder |
| `taxon_superfamily_name` |  |
| `taxon_family_name` | Family |
| `taxon_subfamily_name` | Subfamily |
| `taxon_supertribe_name` |  |
| `taxon_tribe_name` | Tribe |
| `taxon_subtribe_name` | Subtribe |
| `taxon_genus_name` | Genus |
| `taxon_genushybrid_name` |  |
| `taxon_species_name` | Species |
| `taxon_hybrid_name` |  |
| `taxon_subspecies_name` | Subspecies |
| `taxon_variety_name` | Variety |
| `taxon_form_name` | Form |

## Questions

1. Is there a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) on the iNaturalist taxon levels? If not, what are the exceptions?
2. Do I have the taxonomic levels in the right order in my table?

Comment: Wikipedia has another table with some more of these levels: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank#Terminations_of_names

Comment: I am not interested in software recommendations along the lines of "just put your data in `<software_name>` and it will figure it out". I have software solutions. I want a conceptual understanding of the (possibly [partial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialOrder.html) or [total](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotallyOrderedSet.html)) order.

Comment: I'll just point out that these rank-based definitions are highly problematic and not really consistent with current thinking (despite their prevalence on the web). https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55457/why-is-traditional-rank-based-taxomomy-considered-by-some-as-logically-inconsist

Comment: Too echo what @kmm says, these other middle/intervening levels of the hierarchy exist precisely because it doesn't quite work to build a hierarchy like this. When you want to refer to some relevant group, you sometimes have to come up with a new name for it.

Comment: This may be a better question for the [iNaturalist forums](https://forum.inaturalist.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the correct order, based on [this question](https://forum.inaturalist.org/t/api-taxonomy-list-of-available-ranks/4202):

> kingdom
> phylum
> subphylum
> superclass
> class
> subclass
> infraclass
> subterclass
> superorder
> order
> suborder
> infraorder
> parvorder
> zoosection
> zoosubsection
> superfamily
> epifamily
> family
> subfamily
> supertribe
> tribe
> subtribe
> genus
> genushybrid
> subgenus
> section
> subsection
> complex
> species
> hybrid
> subspecies
> variety
> form
> infrahybrid

Note that the hybrid ranks, biologically, break the otherwise strict hierarchy.

[This FAQ](https://www.inaturalist.org/pages/curator%252Bguide#nodes) may also be helpful.